# Type inference fails on parameterized types

Tags: kotlin, polymorphism, higher-kinded-types

Say we have following types:

```
abstract class Generic_B

interface Generic_A<Generic_B>

class Concrete_B : Generic_B()

class Concrete_A : Generic_A<Concrete_B>

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val a = Concrete_A();
    foo(a);
}

fun foo(thing: Generic_A<Generic_B>) {
}
```

I'm getting an error saying:

```
Error:(27, 9) Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is Concrete_A but Generic_A<Generic_B> was expected
```

I don't quite understand the error.

`Concrete_A` is an instance of `Generic_A` and also parameterized on a concrete instance of `Generic_B`.  As such, I feel like the type inference should match up.

I guess me questions are:

1. Why is the type inference not working? (is this a case of higher kinded polymorphism?)
2. How do I work around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you just run into the issue that `Generic_A<Generic_B>` is not the same as `Generic_A<Concrete_B>`, which `Concrete_A` extends.

If you add the `out` variance to the `thing` parameter generic part, you'll have it working, as it would accept all subtypes of `Generic_B`:

```
fun foo(thing: Generic_A<out Generic_B>) {
}
```